# Alter paragraph fields in closed mode

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I was wondering if there is a way to alter paragraph fields when the paragraph is set to "closed" in the Edit mode setting of form display. Because in that case the `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter` does not return any of the inline paragraph fields inside the `$element['subform']`

To give a little more details, there's a paragraph field that holds some more native fields within itself. When I am trying to add/edit the node with which it is attached, i want to alter some fields within the paragraph. Since the paragraph is closed the fields within will be rendered via ajax call on the fly. I was looking for a way to alter them during this ajax call, that is just before they get rendered in the form so that I can alter their attributes.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little more and share some code? Do you want to edit the paragraph field itself, or the way its rendered? The form is not yet rendered in closed mode because the form is rendered on the fly via AJAX when the closed paragraph is opened.

Comment: Well there's a paragraph field that holds some more native fields within itself. When I am trying to add/edit the node with which it is attached, i want to alter some fields within the paragraph. Yes you are right that when the paragraph is closed the fields within will be rendered via ajax call on the fly. But is there a way to alter them during this ajax call, that is just before they get rendered in the form so that I can alter their attributes. I hope I make myself clear.

Comment: Thanks, Pratip. Could you please edit your question to include that information? I've offered an answer that I think might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two approaches you could take here. In the past I've successfully extended the [InlineParagraphsWidget](https://api.md-systems.ch/api/paragraphs/paragraphs%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21InlineParagraphsWidget.php/class/InlineParagraphsWidget/8.x-1.x) field widget in order to alter the form display for Paragraphs. I think that [hook_ajax_render_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/8.2.x) might also be a good solution.

I have not used `hook_ajax_render_alter()`, but I have successfully extended `InlineParagraphsWidget` for the purpose of altering the AJAX response. Specifically, look into overriding the `::addMoreAjax()` and `::formElement()` methods.

Below is a simplified version of the `::addMoreAjax()` callback that I used. Use `$insert_element = parent::addMoreAjax($form, $form_state);` to get a reference to the triggering element.

```
public static function addMoreAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $insert_element = parent::addMoreAjax($form, $form_state);

        // TODO: This is NOT the cleanest way to find the wrapper ID.
        // Find a cleaner way to get these values.
        $wrapper_id = explode('"', $insert_element['#prefix'])[1];
        $pos = strrpos($wrapper_id, '--');
        $wrapper_id = '#' . substr($wrapper_id, 0, $pos);

        // If you needed the field name.
        $field_name = end($insert_element['#parents']);

        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $response->addCommand(new InsertCommand($wrapper_id, $insert_element));
        return $response;
    }
```

You will probably also want to provide validation by overriding `::elementValidate()`.

You will also likely need to implement [hook_field_widget_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info_alter/8.7.x) in order to make your new widget active.

```
function my_module_field_widget_info_alter(array &$info)
{

    $info['entity_reference_paragraphs']['class'] = MyCustomInlineParagraphsWidget::class;
    $info['entity_reference_paragraphs']['provider'] = 'my_module';
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Excellent Beau. Thanks for taking your time out to explain it so well. Let me try these methods to see if this helps. I will append my findings later in this thread.